# Why S.O.E official didn't shoot Max Vatan for not allowing him to investigate Marianne?

Tags: plot-explanation, allied

In *Allied*, Max Vatan denied ***spy allegations*** on Marianne by kicking the chair in front of a S.O.E official.(see the chair position in the IMAGE)

[image]

Actually S.O.E official hiding the gun in the desk.

[image]

But he didn't shoot Max Vatan, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Because we don't shoot people for kicking chairs!

The SOE official has the gun to defend himself *if attacked*.

Vatan isn't attacking the official (or the Army officer) he's just kicking the chair in frustration and outrage....and that's not something to be shot for!

Equally, the SOE **need** Vatan to keep Marianne in place while they identify her handler...another reason not to shoot him.